# cognos performance threshold

Tags: performance, reporting, cognos, threshold

my cognos reporting team have an issue, few reports take 7 mins to fetch report of 3k records, which references 10+ tables, and sufficient indexes in place. At the earlier stage of the project my ex-collegues have given a wrong probmise to client that such reports can be rendered within one minute which doesn't seem to be realistic. I need to negotiate client with some facts. I need some direction. By the way, possible tuning efforts were already done. Only at this stage we were given 3k of test data and realizing the problem. Clients are reasonable, just that I need to explain them with some standards and fact. Any directions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about 3k records in the results or in the source tables? What is the largest number of records among your source tables? Are they organized for optimal reporting, such as a star schema, or are they in a transactional denormalized?

Comment: tks for the response. I meant 3k records as in Results, the tables usually contain 100k over records. And we don't have start schema, all the referring tables are transactional tables.

Comment: As long as your report is pointing to transactional tables and not a proper data warehouse you will have sub-optimal performance. The kind of performance you will receive in practice depends heavily on the back end data source you are reporting from.

Comment: Tks a lot for the response, I understood the limitations

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues while implementing Cognos BI with Oracle 11g database.I was joining more than 10 tables some with more than million records. I managed to optimize it to run within 1 min by

- Using LEFT Joins in SQL
- Creating Functions or Materialized views
- Creating indexes within the tables
- Pasting SQL Directly in Report Studio

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Very important input for me..Tks a lot Dude